# What products are advertised in the game?

Tags: death-stranding

It's hard to miss energy drink product placement in your private room.

But is there anything else? Is whiskey Mads Mikkelsen's character drinks real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Energy drink:

   > Table in private room, backpack attachment, consumable.
2. TV Show with Norman Reedus:

   > Toilet doors in private room, special type of reverse trike.
3. Wine

   > in "Fine Wine" Cliff's memory.